# Linhas em Colunas (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, relatório

Estou ha alguns dias pensando numa forma de tornar um select menos verboso, transformando linhas em colunas. Hoje tenho ele dessa forma:

```
(SELECT s.code_sample
          FROM app_sample s
         WHERE s.id_analysis = a.id
           AND s.sequential_order = '001') AS code_sample_1,
       (SELECT s.code_sample
          FROM app_sample s
         WHERE s.id_analysis = a.id
           AND s.sequential_order = '002') AS code_sample_2,
       (SELECT s.code_sample
          FROM app_sample s
         WHERE s.id_analysis = a.id
           AND s.sequential_order = '003') AS code_sample_3,
       (SELECT s.code_sample
          FROM app_sample s
         WHERE s.id_analysis = a.id
           AND s.sequential_order = '004') AS code_sample_4,
       (SELECT s.code_sample
          FROM app_sample s
         WHERE s.id_analysis = a.id
           AND s.sequential_order = '005') AS code_sample_5,
       (SELECT s.code_sample
          FROM app_sample s
         WHERE s.id_analysis = a.id
           AND s.sequential_order = '006') AS code_sample_6,
       (SELECT s.code_sample
          FROM app_sample s
         WHERE s.id_analysis = a.id
           AND s.sequential_order = '007') AS code_sample_7,
       (SELECT s.code_sample
          FROM app_sample s
         WHERE s.id_analysis = a.id
           AND s.sequential_order = '008') AS code_sample_8,
```

O script acima funciona, porem tenho dois problemas com ele:
**Primeiro** que existem muitas informações que estão em linhas e precisam virar colunas como essa e não são apenas 8 colunas - pode variar até 100 para cada item de acordo com sua sequencia.
**Segundo** que a ordem recebida nem sempre é sequencial, por exemplo ('001', '003', '040'), pois depende da situação.

O script nesse formato fica gigante e inviável de manter, outra é que preciso ordenar o sequencial para que nao haja 'gap' na mostragem do relatório.

Estou aberto a sugestões e discuções.

Grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção seria assim:

```
select a.id , 
sCol001.code_sample as code_sample_1, 
sCol002.code_sample as code_sample_2, 
sCol003.code_sample as code_sample_3, 
sCol004.code_sample as code_sample_4, 
sCol005.code_sample as code_sample_5, 
sCol006.code_sample as code_sample_6, 
sCol007.code_sample as code_sample_7, 
sCol008.code_sample as code_sample_8
from a 
left join app_sample sCol001 on sCol001.id_analysis = a.id and sCol001.sequential_order = '001'
left join app_sample sCol002 on sCol002.id_analysis = a.id and sCol002.sequential_order = '002'
left join app_sample sCol003 on sCol003.id_analysis = a.id and sCol003.sequential_order = '003'
left join app_sample sCol004 on sCol004.id_analysis = a.id and sCol004.sequential_order = '004'
left join app_sample sCol005 on sCol005.id_analysis = a.id and sCol005.sequential_order = '005'
left join app_sample sCol006 on sCol006.id_analysis = a.id and sCol006.sequential_order = '006'
left join app_sample sCol007 on sCol007.id_analysis = a.id and sCol007.sequential_order = '007'
left join app_sample sCol008 on sCol008.id_analysis = a.id and sCol008.sequential_order = '008'
```

E com certeza a query ficará mais rápida.

Abs.

Comment: Legal a sugestão @Rodolpho Sa, diminuiria bem as linhas, porem ainda tenho o problema do sequencial não ser exatamente um sequencial e poder haver falhas. Valeu pela dica.

Comment: Talvez você possa montar uma procedure que gere uma string dinâmica da query (usando este exemplo como modelo ) e depois executa-la.

Answer (score 0):

Jeferson Cruz a melhor forma de ordenar resultados é com o order by e logo em seguida o campo que você quer ordenar, ex: select * from app_sample order by sequential_order.

Pode aproveitar o exemplo do Rodolpho Sa e acrescentar o order by.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.

Citação